# How to make a return to previous page button in Tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

[Link to My python files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ggFAsHTKnTOabw9XCJX-kqmFamR9EMww)

Good evening, I faced a lot of issues to modify my code (homepage.py) in order to create a return button from the signup page back to login page. So how can I do that ? I appreciate any help given.

I tried this

```
 bouton_retour = tk.Button(self.master, text="Retour à la page de connexion", command=self.retour_page_connexion)
        bouton_retour.place(x=50, y=50)

    def retour_page_connexion(self):
        self.master.destroy()  # Ferme la fenêtre d'inscription
        fenetre.deiconify()  # Rétablit la fenêtre de connexion
```

but it didnt work and nothing even changed

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] directly in your question. Offsite code is generally frowned upon here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have both the signup page and the login page in frames you can create a function like this:

```
def switch_to_login():
    signup_frame.pack_forget()
    login_frame.pack()
```

(or grid_forget())

And then just create a button:

```
back_button = tk.Button(signup_frame, text="Back to login", command=switch_to_login)
```